# media breakpoints that work across devices

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova

I have a set of media query breakpoints that are ment to detect when an iPad is in either landscape or portrait. The breakpoints are;

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
```

Now I'm using these for a iPad phonegap app but now I need to expand to Android tablets and that made me wonder if these breakpoints would work across Androide tablets as well? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [responsive scaffolding in Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).  These should help you capture all variations.

Do bear in mind that 'Andriod tablets' come in all different shapes, sizes, and resolutions so it will be very difficult to target them specifically.  Your best bet is to use the flowas shown in Bootstrap to ensure that it looks good at any screen size.

This is achieved in Bootstrap by including fluid-width layouts from 768px downwards.